# Another Friday riddle - We are quite shy

Tags: riddle, poetry

No one knows quite why,
But we are very shy.
You can't touch our crowns,
So far from the ground.
It might have been because,
Of all the bump and grind.
But Ng showed that was false,
When given enough time.
Do you know what I speak of?
I don't think you do.
It will be a long weekend,
So best of luck to you.

Comment: Is Ng a National guard or National Geographic?

Comment: Nope. It's a person's name. Probably hard to google, at that.

Comment: being in Web Development. for me ng is an acronym for Angular which is currently the most popular framework. :-)

Comment: So this Ng doesn't involve the color light purple?

Comment: I'm not certain about that but that sounds like it's waaay off.

Comment: Ng is a surname?

Comment: Yes, Ng is a surname.

Comment: I'm thinking botany/horticulture, am i hot or cold?

Comment: that is indeed close.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28781/discussion-between-kingrames-and-moonbutt74).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So following the discussion in the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28781/discussion-between-kingrames-and-moonbutt74)

Are you looking for

> Crown Shyness (Tree or Dryobalanops)

No one knows quite why,
But we are very shy.
You can't touch our crowns,
So far from the ground.

> Species of some trees are shy to touch each other on the top. Hard to figure.

It might have been because,
Of all the bump and grind.

> Growing up with neighbors so close has its share of bumping and grinding. ;-)

But Ng showed that was false,
When given enough time.

> Scientist/Researcher F.P. Ng showed the theory was [incorrect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crown_shyness).

Do you know what I speak of?
I don't think you do.
It will be a long weekend,
So best of luck to you.

> Red Herrings with a Challenge :-)

Thanks to @Kingrames for another informative quest.

Comment: I was looking for the term "Crown Shyness."

Comment: @Kingrames Thank you. I will correct edit the answer.